# Javascript, глобальное использование this внутри класса

Tags: javascript, node.js, классы, ecmascript-6

Допустим есть такой код

```js
class MyClass{

    constructor(files){
        this.files = files;
    }

    moveUploadedFiles (params,cb){
        this.createFolder(params.dest,function(){
            async.each(this.files, function(file, next) {  //error here, this.files = undefined
                
                //..
            }
        }
                       
    }
    
    createFolder (dir,cb){
        
    }
    
    //....
}
```

Почему, внутри `async.each`, `this.files = undefined`?

Как сделать все что объявляется в конструкторе глобальным внутри класса, даже если это используется во вложенных методах?

p.s. Если не использовать ES6 class, а пользоваться обычным подходом, то можно было ссылку `this` вынести например так: `var $this = this`, и это решало все проблемы (кстати с этим примером тоже решает). Как же сделать это используя новый стандарт ES?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как же сделать это используя новый стандарт ES?

Например, заменить

```
async.each(this.files, function(file, next) {
```

на

```
async.each(this.files, (file, next) => {
```

Comment: можно еще ссылку на доку: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions